# Period finding enables solving the Discrete Logarithm Problem

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, computational-complexity, discrete-logarithms

> Does being able to find the periods enable us to solve the Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP)?

This is what I have got so far:

> Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group with $G = \langle g \rangle$, i.e. $g \in G$ is a generator of $G$. Let further be $h \in G$ such that $h = g^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that we know that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the periods of $g$ and $h$, i.e. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the smallest integers such that
>
> $$g^{p_1} = 1 \text{ and } h^{p_2} = 1.$$
>
> Then we have that
> $$g^{kp_2+p_1} = g^0$$
> $$\Longrightarrow kp_1 + p_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{ \lvert G \rvert}$$
> $$\Longrightarrow kp_1 \equiv -p_2 \pmod{ \lvert G \rvert}.$$

However, I am not sure if we can write $k = -p_2 p_1^{-1} \bmod{ \lvert G \rvert}$, since I am not sure I am not sure that $\gcd(p_1, \lvert G \rvert) = 1$ holds. Could you please help me?

Comment: Under your assumptions, $p_1=|G|$, so you cannot write $p^{-1}$ modulo $|G|$; that means inverting $0$.